# Symfony - csv file reading

Tags: forms, file, symfony, csv, upload

I created a basic form for uploading a csv-file:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ path('path') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label>Csv File</label>
            <input type="file" name="csvFile">
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

And in my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/path" name="path")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($request->request->get('csvFile'));
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    // return response
}
```

But its simly nothing returned..

I know symfony has its own form builder component but i would like to know whats wrong with this snippet.

Any suggestions?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Look at the answer. You are using `$request->request->get('csvFile')` instead of `$request->files->get('csvFile')` .

Answer (score 1):

Add to form enctype="multipart/form-data" and action="{{ path('your_route') }}";

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ path('your_route') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <label>Csv File</label>
    <input type="file" id="csvFile" name="csvFile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

In you Controller you can save and read file:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/uploads/csv/';
        $name = uniqid() . '.csv';

        foreach ($request->files as $uploadedFile) {
            $uploadedFile->move($dir, $name);
        }

        $file = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../web/uploads/csv/" . $name;
```

Comment: hey i edited my question aboth, still does not work, can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
$request->files->get('csvFile');
```

To get your file info